# Aerogel material in Blenderkit - having a little trouble

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

This is specific to the aerogel material from Blenderkit, so not sure how many others have experience with it, but maybe someone more experienced with Blender would still have some ideas.  I lucked out in finding it, because I actually need to use an aerogel in an image, and was really unsure how I was going to create it.  However, rather than simply conforming to the mesh I'm applying it to, it seems to stray a LONG ways.  I have a plane I applied it to, as I only want a thin layer, but it's "misting out" into nearby meshes, and making the image look pretty bad as a result (I love the effect, but for the current project, it really won't do).

Current render:
[image]

You can see it almost looks like I created a giant cube, but no, that's a plane.

I'm not too experienced with using nodes in the composite editor, as I only recently got a new laptop capable of using a newer Blender version (currently on the newest).  Maybe there's something I can do with that?  I hope this doesn't sound like too much of a newbie question...  Another note, is that I get very different results with different rendering engines.  Everything else is pretty much the same, but the aerogel is incredibly different.  In case it helps determine what's happening, I'll post the other renders.  The first is with EEVEE.

Then there's this with Cycles:
[image]

Doesn't even show up, oddly enough.

And workbench:
[image]

Comment: I had no idea what an [aerogel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) is (and what the is the *Knudsen* effect?)... well, never mind, judging by the screenshots, the material uses a *[Volume shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/index.html)*. Check the material. There at least three of them (*Principled Volume*, *Volume Scatter*, *Volume Absorption*) These shaders don't work for planes because planes don't have any volume. Try a *Solidify* modifier to add thickness to the plane. 2) Eevee can't render volumes very well ->"cube style". Better use Cycles.

Comment: To add to what @Blunder meant at the end: _EEVEE_ cannot show a volume shader in the shape of a mesh, it will be a cuboid the size of the object's bounding box. For mesh-shaped volumes you need _Cycles_.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Blunder.  This, indeed, solved the problem.  Feel free to post as an answer.  I added a bit of volume with the Solidify modifier, and rendered with Cycles, and am now getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshots, the material uses a [Volume Shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/index.html). Check the material nodes. There at least three of them *Principled Volume*, *Volume Scatter*, and *Volume Absorption*.

These shaders don't work for planes because planes don't have any volume. Try a ***Solidify* modifier** to add some thickness to the plane.

**Note** that *EEVEE* cannot show a volume shader in the shape of a mesh, it will be a cuboid the size of the object's bounding box. For mesh-shaped volumes you need *Cycles*. *(– Gordon Brinkmann)*